# How to have different set of components (views) in portrait and landscape view in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I am trying to create a calculator similar to the iOS 7 calculator as exercise. In course of that I am working on handling the rotation of the app. I went through the articles present over web and they guide to preserve/define the layout for different rotations using the constraints and this is working fine.

But what I am not able to understand is how can I have different set (additional set) of views(buttons) for landscape and portrait rotations. For example, the iOS calculator gets additional buttons in the landscape mode to turn into scientific calculator.

Comment: You can have all the views all the time, and just hide the ones that are not available on portrait

Comment: Thanks. Could you please guide to some link which demonstrates this?

Comment: You're generally not supposed to ask for off-site resources on SO.

Comment: @dandan78 he did not specify "off-site".

Comment: I'm generally against hiding unused elements. Why don't you just remove the current view and allocate/initialize a new one?

Comment: Look at the calculator app. When you turn the screen, the visible elements make room for the new elements, just shifting. Everything pivots as if they have been there the whole time.

Comment: My understanding is having two views will require having two copies of objects too. So whenever rotation happens, every object needs to be copied.